# FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected ','

Tags: php, laravel

I can´t find my syntax error, thanks you:

```
return '<?php echo \FuWidget::getDesignsList('.$article_id.', unserialize("'.serialize($params).'")); ?>';
```

Comment: Please update your question explaining what you are trying to do. This looks like a code smell and could probably be solved a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you would want to return a string containing php code is beyond me but here you go... you have simply not escaped certain characters.

```
return '<?php echo \FuWidget::getDesignsList(\'.$article_id.\', unserialize("\'.serialize($params).\'")); ?>';
```

I think you're after this though...

```
return \FuWidget::getDesignsList($article_id, unserialize(serialize($params)));
```